# Validação de formulário php e ajax

Tags: php, ajax, formulário, input

Desculpa se a pergunta for boba, mais não conheço muito de ajax  e estou tentando fazer um formulário básico para testar a validação usando ajax e php(se é que é possível). Bom lendo na internet e vendo alguns artigos, até agora cheguei com o código abaixo, mas não está funcionando. Quero que quando a pessoa estiver digitando ou quando enviar o formulário ele faça a validação no php e se caso tenha algum erro ele retorna usando ajax o erro.

*O arquivo ini.php esta minha conexão com o banco de dados, não fiz nenhuma query porque, primeiro gostaria de testar os erros para depois enviar o dado para o banco de dados. E não coloquei outros input pra não complicar, resolvendo um o resto eu me viro.

Obrigado.

HTML:

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" maxlength="20" onBlur="Validate(this.value)"></td>
       <span id="error"><?php echo $error; ?></span>
    </tr>  
  </table>
```

"Ajax":

```
    function Validate(data){

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200){
            document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;  
        }   
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "register.php?q=" + data, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    }
```

PHP:

```
$error = array(
    "Nome é obrigatório.",
    "Somente 20 caracteres são permitidos.",
    "Somente letras e espaços são permitidas."
);

// Get the q parameter from url
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST"){
    if(empty($q)){
        echo $error[0]; 
    } else if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $q)){
        echo $error[2];
    } else if(strlen($q) > 20){
        echo $error[1];
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Pode usar JQuery ou JS Puro ?

Comment: Sim,mais eu sei validar usando Jquery ou JS, gostaria mesmo de validar, usando Ajax, obrigado

Comment: Você não vai validar usando ajax, ou valida no lado cliente (javascript), ou no lado servidor (php, recomendado)

Comment: Dê uma olhadela nesta minha resposta aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/142834/enviando-uma-imagem-e-outros-dados-via-jquery-para-php/142858#142858 . Aí eu valido do lado servidor

Comment: Obrigado pela dica

Comment: Conseguiu ter uma ideia de como se faz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você sempre deve validar no servidor, por questões de segurança (Minha opinião). No caso o Ajax, é mais para a página não precisar recarregar ao dar um retorno para o usuário.

Seguindo seu exemplo fiz um aqui, para vc poder adaptar.

Note que eu retirei o `maxlength="20"`, pois dessa forma ele não permite o usuário adicionar mais do que 20 caracteres(isso para poder usar a validação no back-end).
No seu caso `data` não estava recebendo o valor do `input`, por isso adicionei:

```
var data = document.getElementById("data_id").value;
```

E adicionei esse valor através de um `id` no input, poderia ser de outra forma.

```
 <table>
    <tr>
    <form method="GET" action="register.php">   
      <td><input type="text" name="data_input" id="data_id" placeholder="Nome" ></td>
      <td><input type="submit" value="submit"  name="submit" onclick="Validate();return false;"></td>
       <span id="error"></span>
    </form>
    </tr>  
  </table>
  <script>
    function Validate(){
    var data = document.getElementById("data_id").value;
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "register.php?data_input=" + data, true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200){
           if(xmlhttp.responseText != "ok!"){
                document.getElementById("data_id").value='';
                document.getElementById("data_id").placeholder = xmlhttp.responseText;
                document.getElementById("data_id").focus();
            }

        } 

    };
    xmlhttp.send();


    }
  </script>
```

**register.php**

```
if (isset($_GET["data_input"])) {
    $data = $_GET["data_input"];
    if(empty($data)){
      echo "Nome é obrigatório."; 
    } else if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $data)){
      echo "Somente letras e espaços são permitidas.";
    } else if(strlen($data) > 20){
      echo "Somente 20 caracteres são permitidos.";
    }else{
      echo "ok!";
    }
}
```

Espero ter ajudado, quaquer coisa comenta que agente ajusta.

Comment: Obrigado ajudou muito!

Comment: Apesar que nesse caso estou usando o método GET, o que não é recomendado para dados sensíveis.